# pylons redirect not working on Mac OS

Tags: python, redirect, twitter, pylons

I have a pylons app issuing a redirect to ask for a user to authenticate twitter.

the code in the controller looks something like this:

```
  auth_url = 'http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=mY0aUthaCc3s5T0k3n'
  return redirect( auth_url )
```

But literally nothing happens, only a blank page is rendered.

Now this is where it gets weird. I am only getting this behavior on Mac OS computers. On Ubuntu redirects work just as expected.

This is not a browser thing, since it works on all flavors of browsers on Ubuntu, but those same browsers in Mac OS don't redirect.

Now it gets even weirder, the redirect works for other urls such as

> return redirect('http://google.com')

and even facebook authentication redirect works

> auth_url =
> "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=myId&redirect_uri=http://myurl.com/callback&scope=offline_access"
>
> return redirect( auth_url )

Is this a bug? Am I crazy? Am I doing external redirects wrong?

Comment: Did you try looking at the headers with LiveHTTPHeaders, for example? I'd try to sniff on what exactly is sent to the browser, this may give you some clues.

Answer (score 0):

Try redirect_to.

```
from pylons.controllers.util import redirect_to

class SomeController(BaseController):
    def redirect(self):
        auth_url = 'http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=mY0aUthaCc3s5T0k3n'
        redirect_to( auth_url )
```

This works on my mac.